# Proper data structure to represent a Sudoku puzzle? i.e it should use less memory compared to other data structure used?

Tags: data-structures

Please suggest the solution for the qn?
Proper data structure to represent a Sudoku puzzle? i.e. it should use less memory compared to other data structure used?

Comment: I may be reading this wrong, but what's wrong with a NxN matrix ?

Answer (score 0):

How about `byte[81]` or `byte[9][9]`

Answer (score 0):

Least amount of memory*:

```
byte puzzle[41];

GET_PUZZLE(x,y) = puzzle[(9*y+x)/2] >> ((9*y+x)%2 * 4) & 0x0F;
```

Each number box is stored in 4 bits - so two numbers per byte.

<sub>*Measuring data structure only; not the program memory/etc taken up by the large inefficient `GET_PUZZLE()`.</sub>

---

Ease of use, maintainability, speed, etc:

```
byte puzzle[9][9];

GET_PUZZLE(x,y) = puzzle[x][y]
```

What any sane person would use. Fortunately, it's the most obvious, too.